# Add awc websocket client to add_stream in actix

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm trying to implement a websocket client within the actix framework, but so far I'm having a hard time make this work.

I started with awc websocket client

```
    use actix::{Actor, AsyncContext, Context, Running, StreamHandler, WrapFuture};
use actix_web_actors::ws::{Frame, ProtocolError};
use awc::ws::{Codec, Message};
use awc::BoxedSocket;
use futures::{FutureExt, SinkExt, StreamExt};
use log::info;
use openssl::ssl::SslConnector;
use serde_json::json;
use tokio::net::TcpSocket;

pub struct RosClient {
    pub connection: Option<TcpSocket>,
}

impl RosClient {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { connection: None }
    }
}

impl Actor for RosClient {
    type Context = Context<Self>;

    fn started(&mut self, ctx: &mut Self::Context) {
        let handle = async move {
            let ssl = {
                let mut ssl = SslConnector::builder(openssl::ssl::SslMethod::tls()).unwrap();
                let _ = ssl.set_alpn_protos(b"\x08http/1.1");
                ssl.build()
            };
            let connector = awc::Connector::new().ssl(ssl).finish();
            let ws = awc::ClientBuilder::new()
                .connector(connector)
                .finish()
                .ws("ws://127.0.0.1:9090")
                .set_header("Host", "0.0.0.0:9090");

            let (resp, mut connection) = ws
                .connect()
                .await
                .map_err(|e| {
                    println!("{:?}", e);
                    e
                })
                .unwrap();
            println!("{:?}", resp);
            let message = json!({
                "op": "subscribe",
                "topic": "/client_count"
            })
            .to_string();
            println!("Is write ready {}", connection.is_write_ready());
            let t = connection.send(Message::Text(message)).await.unwrap();
        };
        ctx.spawn(handle.into_actor(self));
        // ctx.add_stream(handle.into_stream());
    }

    fn stopping(&mut self, ctx: &mut Self::Context) -> Running {
        Running::Stop
    }
}

impl StreamHandler<Result<Frame, ProtocolError>> for RosClient {
    fn handle(&mut self, item: Result<Frame, ProtocolError>, ctx: &mut Self::Context) {
        match item.unwrap() {
            Frame::Text(text_bytes) => {
                println!("Text {:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&text_bytes));
            }
            Frame::Binary(_) => {}
            Frame::Continuation(_) => {}
            Frame::Ping(bin) => {
                println!("Ping {:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&bin))
            }
            Frame::Pong(_) => {}
            Frame::Close(_) => {}
        }
    }
}
```

But there are some things I'm still not able to do. The code above is obviously incomplete, but I felt that it would at least provide some starting grounds for the discussion.

- First: How can I implement the add_stream properly?

Right now, I create the future, which allows me to consume from the connection or to send messages from the connection, but I need to add a stream to the context.

- Second: The connection result is a Framed<BoxedSocket, Codec>. I need to keep a reference to the connection somewhere, so that I can send messages to the server. Right now, I can't just do self.connection = connection, because I can't clone it.

So, what would be the right way of implementing that?

Thank you,
Fabricio

Answer (score 1):

I've solved half my problem. I was able to get the streamhandler to work. This is the updated code:

```
use std::time::Instant;

use actix::prelude::*;
use actix_codec::Framed;
use actix_web_actors::ws::{Frame, ProtocolError};
use awc::BoxedSocket;
use awc::ws::Codec;
use futures::StreamExt;
use log::info;
use openssl::ssl::SslConnector;

pub struct RosClient {
    pub address: String,
    pub connection: Option<Framed<BoxedSocket, Codec>>,
    pub hb: Instant,
}

impl RosClient {
    pub fn new(address: &str) -> Self {
        Self {
            address: address.to_string(),
            connection: None,
            hb: Instant::now(),
        }
    }
}

impl Actor for RosClient {
    type Context = Context<Self>;

    fn started(&mut self, ctx: &mut Self::Context) {
        info!("Connecting to ROS client on {}", &self.address);
        let ssl = {
            let mut ssl = SslConnector::builder(openssl::ssl::SslMethod::tls()).unwrap();
            let _ = ssl.set_alpn_protos(b"\x08http/1.1");
            ssl.build()
        };
        let connector = awc::Connector::new().ssl(ssl).finish();
        let ws = awc::ClientBuilder::new()
            .connector(connector)
            .finish()
            .ws(&self.address)
            .set_header("Host", "0.0.0.0:9090");

        let _message = serde_json::json!({
            "op": "subscribe",
            "topic": "/client_count"
        });

        ws.connect()
            .into_actor(self)
            .map(|res, _act, ctx| match res {
                Ok((client_response, frame)) => {
                    info!("Response: {:?}", client_response);
                    let (_r, w) = frame.split();
                    let _ = ctx.add_stream(w);
                }
                Err(err) => {
                    info!("Websocket Client Actor failed to connect: {:?}", err);
                    ctx.stop();
                }
            })
            .wait(ctx);
    }

    fn stopping(&mut self, _ctx: &mut Self::Context) -> Running {
        Running::Stop
    }
}

impl StreamHandler<Result<Frame, ProtocolError>> for RosClient {
    fn handle(&mut self, item: Result<Frame, ProtocolError>, _ctx: &mut Self::Context) {
        match item.unwrap() {
            Frame::Text(text_bytes) => {
                let text = std::str::from_utf8(text_bytes.as_ref()).unwrap();
                info!("Message: {}", text);
            }
            Frame::Binary(_) => {}
            Frame::Continuation(_) => {}
            Frame::Ping(_) => {
                info!("Ping received!");
            }
            Frame::Pong(_) => {
                self.hb = Instant::now();
            }
            Frame::Close(_) => {}
        }
    }
}
```

So, now I'm able to receive messages whenever they come. The only remaining thing to figure out is:

- How do I keep a reference (or handle, or copy, or anything that does the job) to the connection, so that when I implement the message handlers, I can send data `Message::Text(message.to_string())` to the server?

Comment: It may be worth raising your remaining question as a new question. Answers aren't a good location to posit follow-up questions.

Comment: Sure. I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: Here's the link to the follow-up question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70118994/build-a-websocket-client-using-actix